# Cannot get Elasticsearch Highlight to work

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a project that involves Elasticsearch. So far I can get most function to work except highlight. I am using Laravel + Elasticsearch official PHP client.

Previously I thought it was a problem of my PHP code, and asked a question here:
[highlight field missing from Elasticsearch results, PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406841/highlight-field-missing-from-elasticsearch-results-php)

Later when I tried with elasticsearch-head in browser, I still cannot see highlight field in results, so I guess there must be something wrong with either my settings of elasticsearch or the way I indexed the documents.

Here is the query I entered into elasticsearch-head:

```
{
"query" : {
    "match" : {
        "combined" : "DNA"
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "fields" : {
        "combined" : {}
    }
}
}
```

And I don't see  "highlight" after "_source" in hits returned by elasticsearch.

What might I did wrong here?

Please advise,

Thanks.

Update: I'm running Elasticsearch 2.3.3, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop, JDK 1.8.

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) says "store" in mapping needs to be set true. I did so, and re-indexed a bunch of documents. This didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What is your mapping? And please give a one document example...

Comment: I followed the example here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_index_management_operations.html
The advanced example with slight customization. Later on as I stated in answer, the problem is really "store" needs to be set true. Something I overlooked at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

OK, after stopping and restarting elasticsearch service, my code started to work as intended. I got "highlight" field in results.

The issue is that I need to set "store" to true. Everything else being equal, including the following line

```
"store"   =>   true
```

in mapping ensured "highlight" appear in the results I have. Vice versa.

Not sure why doing this earlier didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Where do you add "store" => true ?